# Pass value by pointer error

Tags: c++, pointers

I don't understand why is crashing. I send a pointer to an array, alloc that array and then modify array. What is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void f(unsigned char *data) {
    data = (unsigned char *)malloc(200);
}

int main() {
    unsigned char *data = nullptr;
    int i;
    f(data);
    memset(data, 0, 200);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how a program that doesn't compile can crash.

Comment: Please don't post code with `void main`, because that fails to compile with many compilers. Also it's non-standard and teaches ungood habits. FTFY.

Comment: Note: this declaration creates an array of 200 bytes and sets it to zero: `unsigned char data[200] = {};`.

Comment: You don't send a pointer to an array, you send a null pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
 void f(unsigned char *data) { // ....
```

to

```
 void f(unsigned char *&data) { // ....
                    // ^
 }
```

or

```
 void f(unsigned char **data) {
     *data = (unsigned char *)malloc(200);
 }
```

and call

```
 f(&data);
// ^
```

---

It's all about passing a reference to the `data` pointer to be initialized from within the function.

Your example passes `data` by value, and doesn't change the pointer outside of the function.

Answer (score 6):

You are passing `data` by value to `f()`.

`f()` sets the value of its parameter.

Because the parameter was passed by value, this does absolutely nothing to the `data` variable in `main()`. `f()` leaks the allocated memory, and when it returns, `main()`'s `data` is still `nullptr`.

You should pass it by reference:

```
void f(unsigned char *&data)
```

Or, better yet, return it. `f()` doesn't need the parameter.

```
unsigned char *f() {
    return (unsigned char *)malloc(200);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The call to `f` does not change the value of the variable `data` defined in `main`, as you seem to expect it to.  It changes the value of the `data` defined in `f`, but because parameters are passed by value, that has no effect on the `data` defined in `main`.